# JQuery toggle() is called from different div than the one specified

Tags: jquery, toggle

Good day sirs.

I have two divs, one is a sidebar which is hidden by default and could be slide-toggled.
And the other one is some kind of top bar that contains an icon which is when clicked will trigger the hidden bar to slide.
I could get it to work by doing this in index.html:

```
<div id="top-toolbar">
    <div id="toggler-button"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="img/gear-40px.png" /></a></div>
</div>
<div id="toggled-bar"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $("#toggler-button").click(function(){
        $("#toggled-bar").toggle("slide");
    });
});
</script>
```

and my css looks like this:

```
#top-toolbar {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top:0%;
box-shadow: 3px 0px 3px black;
background-color: #FFF;
z-index: 2;
}

#toggler-button {
position: relative;
margin: 5px;
}

#toggled-bar {
position: fixed;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px black;
width: 200px;
height: 350px;
top: 50px;
background-color:#FFF;
display: none;
z-index: 1;
}
```

[I put it here](http://jsfiddle.net/c2HnC/1/), and somehow it work different from what I intend, the entire top bar could be clicked to trigger the sliding. This might be a very noob question, but how could I tweak this so that the toggling only occurs when the image is clicked, not the entire top bar?
I think I declare the function to trigger the toggling correctly.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Add a class to image & $(".imgclass").click(function() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$("#toggler-button img")` instead of `$("#toggler-button")`, or give the image an ID/Class and select it .via that.

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/c2HnC/3/)

Answer (score 2):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c2HnC/1/)

change this

`$("#toggler-button")`

to

`$("#toggler-button img")`

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#toggler-button img").click(function () {
        $("#toggled-bar").toggle("slide");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that such a basic mistake I make.